# having error when download package from Github in R?

Tags: r, github, error-handling, package, devtools

I need to install the package from Github. More precisely [ggsankey](https://github.com/davidsjoberg/ggsankey), however, when I run this code there is an error:

```
   devtools::install_github("davidsjoberg/ggsankey")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.

Please download and install Rtools 4.2 from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ or https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/winutf8/ucrt3/.
Downloading GitHub repo davidsjoberg/ggsankey@HEAD
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  cannot open URL 'https://api.github.com/repos/davidsjoberg/ggsankey/tarball/HEAD'
```

Comment: Did you download Rtools successfully?

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: can I Istall it from RStudio?

Comment: How can I check if Rtools is already instaled or not?

Comment: You can install it from RStudio with installr if you want, `install.packages("installr");library(installr);install.Rtools(check = TRUE)`